# React setting state in componentWillReceiveProps - for this component and parent component - anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, properties, components, state

The code below works nicely in my app. It seems like an anti-pattern though:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.conversation.length > this.props.conversation.length){
        if (this.state.hideDiv) {
            this.setState({
                hideDiv: false,
            });
        }
        this.props.incrementNotificationCount();
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

`componentWillReceiveProps` checks if `nextProps` conversation array is larger than `this.props` coversation array. Meaning: I received a new conversation message.

If I *did* receive a new message, I want to show a div *only if* it is hidden, In `this` component I have local state of `hideDiv`.

If hidden:

```
if (this.state.hideDiv)
```

Show it:

```
this.setState({ 
    hideDiv: false,
}).
```

Also, if I *did* receive a new message, I want to increment the notification count which is in a `parent component`:

```
this.props.incrementNotificationCount()
```

This method causes the notification `state` to be changed in the `parent component`.

**Question**:

I know setting *local* `state` in `componentWillReceiveProps` will not cause a `rerender`. But what happens if I set the `state` of a `parent component` in `componentWillReceiveProps`?

And is this code an "anti-pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the parent component rerenders, `componentWillReceiveProps` in child is called before the child render function is called. In this function if you call `setState` for the `childComponent`, the next state is updated in the `componentWillUpdate` function and then received by the render in the child.

Also when you call the parent function in the `componentWillReceiveProps` which updates the parent state, the parent is `rerendered` and thus the child rerenders again.

See a sample snippet which demostrates the same behaviour

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
      childState: 1,
      mystate: 2,
    }
    changeState = () => {
        console.log('change state in parent called');
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            mystate: prevState.mystate + 1
        }))
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('cwu parent', nextState);
    }
    changeChildState = () => {
       console.log('change child state called');
       this.setState((prevState) => ({
           childState: prevState.childState + 1
           })
       )
    }
    render() {
        console.log('Parent rerender called');
        return (
           <div>
             <div> Parent {this.state.mystate}</div>
             <button onClick={() => this.changeChildState()}>Click</button>
             <MyComponent val={this.state.childState} changeState={this.changeState}/> 
           </div>
        )
    }
    
   
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        state = {
            someChildState: 1
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if(nextProps.val !== this.props.val) {
               console.log('child cwrp called');
              this.setState((prevState) => ({someChildState: prevState.someChildState + 1}));
               this.props.changeState();
            }
        }
        componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
           console.log(nextState)
        }
        render() {
           console.log('child render called')
           return <div > {this.props.val} {this.state.someChildState} </div>
        }
    }
    
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: `Also when you call the parent function in the componentWillReceiveProps which updates the parent state, the parent is rerendered and thus the child rerenders again` . --------- Is it possible to tell what will happen first? Will the parent state rerender or will the local state of the child component get changed first?

Comment: Adding the componentWillUpdate function in the parent, you can see that the local state of the child is changed first causing its rerender first before the parent state is changed. I hope it has helped :)